# VBScript pulse (0 & 1)

Tags: vbscript

How to generating pulse using VBScript?

I tried with `Timer` function, but no idea how to use it.

```
t1 = Timer 
temp = Int(t1)
Seconds = temp mod 60

strTime = String(2 - Len(Hours), "0") & Hours & ":"
strTime = strTime & String(2 - Len(Minutes), "0") & Minutes & ":"
strTime = strTime & String(2 - Len(Seconds), "0") & Seconds
```

Comment: For one thing your code is a) incomplete and b) broken (`t1 =` and `temp =` must not be on the same line unless separated with a colon). Aside from that it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve in the first place. What "pulse" are you trying to generate? What did you expect from your code? What did you actually get?

Comment: I have check box to enable the function (File Watcher). Once i enable, continuously watch the file inside the folder which will be written in File watcher function.
I tried, but only one time the function is working when i enable the checkbox. So, i would like to generate pulse with timer to enable & disable the check box automatically.

Comment: Sorry, but the only thing your comment clarifies is that this is likely an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] for your actual problem rather than what you perceive as the solution.